# Question about the array's address in C++

Tags: c++

I have a question about the array's address.

Is `*(a + *a)` the same as `a[3]`? If it is, please give me some explanation.

```cpp
int main() {

     int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

     *(a + *a);

}
```

Comment: 1) Certainly not, `(a + *a)` is an `int*` while `a[3]` is an `int`. 2) Why `[3]`?

Comment: `(a + *a)` is `&a[1]`.

Comment: `(a + *a)` = `(a + a[0])` = `(a + 1)` = `&a[1]`  the same as `a` = `(a + 0)` = `&a[0]`

Comment: Sorry guys, actually, I want to know *(a+*a) == a[3]??

Comment: @HmL `*(a + *a)` is the same as `a[a[0]]`.  So you are asking if `2 == 4`.

Comment: The answer is "no".  Why do you think so?  `*(a+*a)` is 2.

Comment: @dxiv Oh sorry.. I'm confused because sometimes I get the different value. For example,

The output below code is 4.

Why is *(arr + *arr)'s result 4 in this case..??
```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

     int a[] = { 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

     std::cout << *(arr+ *arr);

}
```

Comment: @HmL Because `a[0] == 1` in the question, while `a[0] == 3` in this latest comment. So in the first case `a[a[0]]` = `a[1]` = `2`, while in the second case `a[a[0]]` = `a[3]` = `4`.

Comment: @dxiv Oh!! I got it.. That's why.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless you're trying to win an [obfuscated code contest](https://www.ioccc.org), please, *never* write code like this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is (a + *a) same as a[3]??

No, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is the address of the first element of the array. `*a` is the value located at the first element of the array. So `a+*a` is the sum of those two values, which is not the same as `a[3]`.

If the first element of the array happened to be `3`, then `*(a+*a)` would be the same as `a[3]`. But that is not the situation you have. i.e. `*a=3`, `(a+3)` is the location of the fourth element of `a`, `*(a+3)` is the element at the fourth location of the array, which is also accessible using `a[3]`.

Comment: Oh why is *(a+*a) == a[3]??

Comment: @dxiv,  thanks for pointing out the off-by-one error. I'll update to correct.

Answer (score 1):

No. `*a` is equal to 1, so `cout << a + 1` will output address of a incremented by 4, which is the size of an int type. This is because a is an array of int, so every increment will add it's address by `sizeof(int)`, which is 4.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize for a given `X* x` or `X x[]` that can decay into a pointer:

1. `*(x + y)` is the same as `x[y]`.
2. `*x` is the same as `x[0]`

In effect `*(a + *a)` is just a really confusing way of writing `a[a[0]]`, so the way it evaluates depends entirely on what `a[0]` is.

In this case it's `1`, so you get `a[a[0]]` or `a[1]` as the result.